# Qual a diferença entre Text Box e Input?

Tags: winforms, formulário, input, textbox, protótipo

tô fazendo um protótipo de média fidelidade no aplicativo Pencil e gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre um campo Text Box e o Input e quando utilizá-los:

[image: protótipo cadastro]
Obrigada!

Answer (score -1):

O Pencil oforece várias abastrações. HTML, Desktop, Phone e etc.

Um campo input é o nome genérico para diversos tipos.

Então vou explicar usando o HTML, o input é o nome genérico. Você precisa informar o tipo[1] o campo do tipo text (no pencil seria o text box) é tipo mais simples para fornecer um campo[2], cuidado para não confundir com o textarea que é para texto longo [3]

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

[2] https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_text

[3] https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea